# Python, search for text on the line immediately below a known string?

Tags: python, regex, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script using the python module BeautifulSoup to get the xml from a webpage. This webpage contains information describing a project using genomic data and I want to extract all of the PUBMED IDs (unique ID numbers for the publications that came from this project). Each PUBMED ID is an 8 digit number.

I've tried two different methods to extract the PUBMED IDs but there are problems with both. Firstly, I used this code to extract the complete xml:

```
url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB2357&display=xml'
project_page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser")
print soup
```

The output of this command looks a bit like this:

```
<db>PUBMED</db>
<id>25101644</id>
</xref_link>
</project_link>
<project_link>
<xref_link>
<db>PUBMED</db>
<id>24509479</id>
```

(obviously this is not the entirety of the xml, just the section that is relevant to me).

The BeautifulSoup module contains a number of commands which search through this soup for text of interest but as far as I can tell they all take either the tag or the text being searched for as input. I can't use either of these here because there are multiple segments of text other than the PUBMED ID on this page that have the same xml tag (`<id>`), and I clearly can't search for the PUBMED ID using the text if I don't know what it is!

The second method I tried was printing just the text from the xml using this code:

```
url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB2357&display=xml'
project_page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser") 
text = soup.text
print text
```

This time the output looks like this:

```
PUBMED
25101644




PUBMED
24509479
```

I had a couple of ideas at this point. Firstly the python re module (regex in earlier versions of python) could be used to search for the expression but again all re commands that I know of require at least a portion of the pattern being searched for as input so I don't think that this alone is an option. Secondly, I tried to do something like this:

```
url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB2357&display=xml'
project_page = urlopen(url)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "html.parser") 
text = soup2.text
text = text.replace('\n', ' ').replace(' ', '') #removes all spaces and linebreaks
PMID = re.findall('PUBMED........', text, flags = 0)
print PMID
```

This gives this output:

```
[u'PUBMED25101644', u'PUBMED24509479']
```

So theoretically this could be converted to a string and I just cut out the relevant 8 digit numbers, but this is getting very hacky and I want to run this script many times over on the webpages for several thousand projects and the number of PUBMED IDs for each project will vary, so this method doesn't lend itself to automation very well.

What I want is a method of searching for every instance of the word "PUBMED", either in the raw soup or in the text and extracting just the PUBMED ID which will be on the next line down. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the look behind in the regex expression.
If the text is

```
print text
PUBMED
25101644




PUBMED
24509479
```

By using the

```
>>> re.findall('(?<=PUBMED\n).+',text)
['25101644', '24509479']
```

If you want to get only the digits that follow the known string replace `.+` with `[\d]+` and it would only select the digits.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that works really well apart from the very last bit, my output looks like this:   [u'25101644', u'24509479'] even when I include the  [\d]+ option...

Comment: That is because the text is a unicode string. You can try one more line like this to get a list of integers

Comment: results = [int(item) for item in re.findall('(?<=PUBMED\n).+',text) ]

Answer (score 1):

Find all occurrences of `PUBMED` and get the [*next siblings*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
[pubmed.find_next_sibling("ID").get_text() 
 for pubmed in soup.find_all("DB", text="PUBMED")]
```

Or, make a [*search function*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
search = lambda tag: tag.name == "ID" and tag.find_previous_sibling("DB", text="PUBMED")
print([pubmed.get_text() for pubmed in soup.find_all(search)])
```

Note that you should be using `xml` parser and not the `html.parser`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "xml")
```

---

DEMO:

```
In [1]: from urllib2 import urlopen

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/PRJEB2357&display=xml'

In [4]: project_page = urlopen(url)

In [5]: soup = BeautifulSoup(project_page, "xml")

In [6]: [pubmed.find_next_sibling("ID").get_text() 
   ...:  for pubmed in soup.find_all("DB", text="PUBMED")]
Out[6]: [u'25101644', u'24509479']

In [7]: search = lambda tag: tag.name == "ID" and tag.find_previous_sibling("DB", text="PUBMED")

In [8]: [pubmed.get_text() for pubmed in soup.find_all(search)]
Out[8]: [u'25101644', u'24509479']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find `db` and then get its first sibling

```
data = '''<db>PUBMED</db>
<id>25101644</id>
</xref_link>
</project_link>
<project_link>
<xref_link>
<db>PUBMED</db>
<id>24509479</id>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
#print(soup)

for x in soup.find_all('db'):
    print(x.text, x.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text)
```

result

```
PUBMED 25101644
PUBMED 24509479
```